# PySpark : Write Spark Dataframe to Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to load dataframe to Kafka Topic. I am getting error on selecting the key and value.

Below is my code:

```
data = spark.sql('select * from job')

kafka = data.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .writeStream.outputMode(outputMode='Append').format('kafka')\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("topic", "Jim_Topic")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "C:/Hadoop/Data/CheckPointLocation/")\
    .start()

kafka.awaitTermination()
```

Below is the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`key`' given input columns: [job.JOB_ID, 
job.JOB_TITLE, job.MAX_SALARY, job.MIN_SALARY]; line 1 pos 5;
'Project [unresolvedalias(cast('key as string), None), unresolvedalias(cast('value as string), None)]
+- Project [JOB_ID#0, JOB_TITLE#1, MIN_SALARY#2, MAX_SALARY#3]
   +- SubqueryAlias `job`
      +- StreamingRelation
```

`DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@1f3fc47a,csv,List(),Some(StructType(StructField(JOB_ID,StringType,true), StructField(JOB_TITLE,StringType,true), StructField(MIN_SALARY,StringType,true), StructField(MAX_SALARY,StringType,true))),List(),None,Map(sep -> ,, header -> false, path -> C:/Hadoop/Data/Job*.csv),None), FileSource[C:/Hadoop/Data/Job*.csv], [JOB_ID#0, JOB_TITLE#1, MIN_SALARY#2, MAX_SALARY#3]`

Comment: What is `job`??

Comment: Job is a temp view of dataframe `dfCSV.createOrReplaceTempView('job')`

Comment: Does it have a `key` and `value` column?

Answer (score 0):

Tried converting the values into json, it worked perfectly. Now am able to send the messages from spark stream to kafka,

```
kafka = data.selectExpr("CAST(JOB_ID AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")\
```